# ORACLE 11g Ejecutar Trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

¿Como asigno los privilegios a un usuario para ejecutar un trigger?, necesito saber si se puede ejecutar un trigger y como asginar los privilegios si es posible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los [`triggers`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm) o disparadores que pueden estar relacionados a tablas no requieren un permiso directo para su ejecución. Pero las tablas a las que pueden estar asignados si.

Los disparadores pueden ejecutarse en diferentes ocasiones:

- [`Before Insert`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_insert.php)
- [`After Insert`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php)
- [`Before Update`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_update.php)
- [`After Update`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_update.php)
- [`Before Delete`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_delete.php)
- [`After Delete`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_delete.php)

Según los permisos que el usuario tenga sobre las tablas para los eventos de `inserción`, `actualización` y `eliminación` también podrá ejecutar los disparadores relacionados a las tablas.